# Performing an action in Eclipse after period of inactivity

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm programming some views and editors in eclipse and have the following problem.

How do I make something happen only after a certain period of "inactivity"?

So my problem is this. I have a view that displays information from a certain model. The model sends events when it updates, but sometimes can send a flood of events. Rather than causing my view to redraw on every single event, I want to make the event set a timer and only if that timer expires without another event coming in do I want to actually update my view. However I can't find a way of doing this. The best I can find is the `Display.timerExec` method, but I'd have to invoke that on each event and then check some timestamp to see whether another event has arrived in the mean time.

I've looked at the plain java Timer classes but they don't appear to provide me with a resettable timer either.

Anyone any ideas how I can achieve what I want to do?

Comment: you could either create a new Timer object every time the previous Timer expires, or create a new class in your project that extends Timer with the method reset() which returns a new instance of that class.

Comment: @keepitreal89: Not sure what you mean here. You're talking of using java.util.Timer? You'll have to expand on your suggestion I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Try UiJobs
-> http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJobs/article.html

Comment: Not sure I see how the jobs frameworks helps me. I have a job whose task is to do the update. When an event comes in I schedule the job for a certain delay. When another event comes in I cancel the job and reschedule?

Comment: take a look at the apidoc -> http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/progress/UIJob.html

Comment: I'm familiar with the API of Jobs, I was wondering what you had in mind when you responded, other than, ooh it sounds a bit like asynchronous stuff, so UIJobs will do.

Comment: Also the problem with Jobs is that they appear in the Progress window, which isn't desirable.

Comment: e.g.: when you type the first letter you start the uijob which will do some action after a period of inactivity. when you type the next letter, you will stop the job and restart it.

Comment: if you have the eclipse source you should take a look at the class org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler
it's a very good example how to do something like decorating some ui element after some time of inactivity

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a bucket of tasks and a thread that reads the bucket. Track the time of last addition to the bucket. Have the thread sleep for the period of delay that you want. When it wakes up, it should see if time of last addition exceeds the delay and perform tasks if it does.

Here is my implementation from the Sapphire project:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.sapphire/plugins/org.eclipse.sapphire.ui/src/org/eclipse/sapphire/ui/DelayedTasksExecutor.java?view=markup&revision=1.2&root=Technology_Project

Feel free to copy if you are able to comply with EPL terms. Otherwise, use the concepts to build your own implementation.